# no shard available action exception on kibana discover

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

when i wanted to view the logs on kibana, i recieved this error :
`1 of 37 shards failed The data you are seeing might be incomplete or wrong.` 
this is Response:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 21,
    "successful": 20,
    "skipped": 20,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "tourism-2022.12.11",
        "node": null,
        "reason": {
          "type": "no_shard_available_action_exception",
          "reason": null,
          "index_uuid": "j2J6dUvTQ_q7qeyyU56bag",
          "shard": "0",
          "index": "tourism-2022.12.11"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

i delete some indexes

expand pvc
but doesnt work anything

Comment: Run GET _cat/indices and GET _cat/shards and add response here.

Comment: @hamidbayat where i can run this request?

Answer (score 0):

Via Kibana console check the cluster status, if you haven't got Kibana available convert the command to curl request.

1. Check the Elasticsearch cluster status:
   `GET /_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=50s`
2. Check index status:
   `GET /_cat/indices/tourism-2022.12.11?v=true&s=index`

All shards are green, have you got documents available in your index ?

Comment: return this response: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: Can paste the request make via curl ?